# Laravel: User and Role Relationship ( User has only 1 Role)

Tags: php, laravel

So I added a column to `Users table` for user role which is `role`;
The User can only have one role, role returns **`null`**

**Role.php (Model)**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'role'
    ];

    public function users() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

**User.php (Model)**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'role', 'first_login', 'last_login', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function role() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
    }
}
```

**UserController.php (index only)**

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::with('role')->get();

    return view('users.index')->with('users', $users);
}
```

**index.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <h1>USERS</h1>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Role</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach($users as $user)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$user->first_name}} {{$user->last_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
                    <td>{{$user->role}}</td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</div>
@endsection
```

User role is **null**.
How to properly do it ?

table structure

```
+-------+
| Users |
+-------+
| id    |
| role  | -> id of role
| ...   |
+-------+


+-------+
| Roles |
+-------+
| id    |
| role  | -> name of role
| ...   |
+-------+
```

Comment: What's your real column name for role?

Comment: in Users Table its role also.

Comment: This is a one-to-one relationship. The user model should `hasOne..` while the role model should `belongsTo...`. See [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one).

Answer (score 3):

By default it will search for `role_id` column in your users table, if its not like that then you need to specify that column in relation. Change your relation to following:

```
public function role() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Role', 'role');
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: By default it will read role column to be role_id, but if its not that then you need to specify it.

Comment: edit the answer ^^ I knew, but the docs don't make it really clear, and I think most people struggle

Comment: Now the role is not empty, but when displaying the role name, I got error. `$user->role->role;`

Comment: @KamalPaliwal `Trying to get property 'role' of non-object` . if I echo $user , role contains the role object, but when $user->role, id is displayed

Comment: Try printing $user->toArray(), check if you are getting role object in it/

Comment: @KamalPaliwal $user->toArray() is error . but when i directly echo $user I got this  `{"id":1,"first_name":"Louie","last_name":"Stacey","email":"ssawayn@example.com","email_verified_at":"2018-11-15 09:47:17","role":{"id":2,"role":"Creator","created_at":"2018-11-15 09:47:17","updated_at":"2018-11-15 09:47:17"},"first_login":null,"last_login":null,"created_at":"2018-11-15 09:47:17","updated_at":"2018-11-15 09:47:17"}`  but $user->role displays the id

Comment: Try changing the name of the relation and from role to something else and then try it

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
public function role() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Role', 'role');
}
```

> belongsTo function document

```
$this->belongsTo(modelName,foregin key,local key)
```

> for hasMany function

```
$this->hasyMany(modelName,foregin key,local key)
```